# Overwrite entry in zip file

Tags: c#, overwrite, dotnetzip

I'm having trouble, I got this code:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles();
DirectoryInfo[] d = di.GetDirectories();
if(rgFiles != null && d != null) {
foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dii in d)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(locateZipFile()))
        {

            zip.AddFile(fi.FullName, "");

            zip.AddDirectory(dii.FullName,dii.Name);
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Inserting " + fi.Name;
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Inserting " + dii.Name + " and all of it's contents";

            MessageBox.Show("Inserted the file " + fi.Name);
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted the folder " + dii.Name + " and all contents in it.");
            zip.Save();

        }
    }
}
```

Everything works great, but when I'm trying to add a file that is named the same in the zip, it does not overwrite it, which i want it to.. Any ideas on how i can do that? thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [UpdateFile](https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/befd3197-f060-b25c-c07f-3f1816bcc7ca.htm) method.

```
zip.UpdateFile(fi.FullName, "");
```

> This method adds a file to a zip archive, or, if the file already exists in the zip archive, this method Updates the content of that given filename in the zip archive. The UpdateFile method might more accurately be called "AddOrUpdateFile".
>
> Upon success, there is no way for the application to learn whether the file was added versus updated.

Answer (score 2):

Before the line

```
zip.AddFile(fi.FullName, "");
```

you must test if the name already exists in entries. If yes, remove it and then insert it again.

Comment: Thanks it worked! but this does not work on directories? how would i do if it's a directory?

Comment: You can use the GetDirectoryName method: Path.GetDirectoryName(fi.FullName); (Don't forget to mark this as response! ;))